# How do I use eager loading with a repository pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, eager-loading

I'm trying to clean up the way I am accessing my data within my application.  I have started moving to a respository pattern and one of the first issues that I encountered was accessing my related data.

After some research I saw that you can use .Include() to access that related data but I can't seem to get it to work nor am I certain the way I have this set up is correct.

How do I use eager loading within a repository pattern?  I have included my code to show you a road map of how I am setting things out.  I've omitted certain items to keep things short and simple.

**IRepository.cs**

```
public interface ICustomerRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<customer> GetRelatedData();          
}
```

**CustomerRepository.cs**
Here I have added the eager loading by specifying the .Include and then defining the related table.

```
public IEnumerable<customer> GetRelatedData()
{
    return context.customers
        .Include(x => x.customer_cars)
        .ToList();
}
```

**CustomerController.cs**
I thought at this level the GetRelatedData would make use of include as defined in the CustomerRepository.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var customers = customersRepository.GetRelatedData();
    return View(customers);
}
```

**The Index View**
I now need to show the data but I am stuck at this stage as I'm unsure how to show the related data in my view.

```
@model IEnumerable<Titan.Models.customer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.first_name)
        </th>    
    </tr>  
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.first_name)
    </td>       
</tr>
}

 </table>
```

It could be that my approach is incorrect I've taken guidance from the ASP.NET MVC tutorial but I can't get my head around how I can make this eager loading scenario work in a repository pattern.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've re-read this twice and I'm still not certain what you are asking.  Are you asking how you get to the child customer_cars object?

Comment: I'm asking two things really a) Is my approach correct for getting the related data using eager loading within a repository pattern? and b) If so how do I get the 'customers_car' object into my view so that I can show this related data?

Comment: Please post the code for your "customer" class

Answer (score 0):

You should have customer car collection in customer object.

Something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
   @foreach(var car in item.customer_cars){
  <td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(car => car.model)
  </td>       
 }
</tr>
}
```